# Ajax not working... part 2

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have several buttons that when you click on each one of them a check image turns on or off (the buttons are part of a table that requests info from a mysql query, and it's length depends on the number of mysql results).

I had the script made with php and mysql, but since I needed a form to post data to that page and couldn't refresh I'm now stuck with ajax.

I have a PHP file: "phpcode.php"

CÔR  is the binnary variable that turns on and off the image and keyword is the primary key in the mysql table

```
<?php

    $n = "SELECT `CÔR` FROM `keywords` WHERE `keyword`='$keyword'";
    $b = mysql_query ($n);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($b);

    $t = $row['CÔR'];
    if ($t == 1) {
    $m = "UPDATE `keywords` SET `CÔR`=0 WHERE `keyword`='$keyword'";
    mysql_query ($m);
        }
    if ($t == 0) {
    $l = "UPDATE `keywords` SET `CÔR`=1 WHERE `keyword`='$keyword'";
    mysql_query ($l);
        }

?>
```

That is called by the javascipt code…

```
document.getElementById('ajaxButton').onClick = function ('$keyword') { url = 'phpcode.php'; makeRequest(url);}
function makeRequest(url) {httpRequest.open('GET', url);}
```

The javascript is triggered by the button...

```
$query = "SELECT `CÔR`, `keyword`, `Adds`, `PRMédio`, `PRDomínioMédio`, `Searches`, `CPC`, `.com`, `.org`, `.net`, `All in URL`, `All in Title`, `All in Desc.`
FROM keywords WHERE ( `Adds`>='$adds'  && `Adds`<='$addsm' && `PRMédio`>='$pr' && `PRMédio`<='$prm' && `PRDomínioMédio`>= '$prdom' && `PRDomínioMédio`<= '$prdommax'
&& `Searches`>='$s' && `Searches`<='$smax' && `CPC`>='$cpc' && `CPC`<='$cpcmax')";  

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){


while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

    (... code)

$keyword = $query_row['keyword'];


    (... code)

include('.php');

echo "

<button id='ajaxButton' method 'GET'>Select</button>

       (... code)
```

This is the second time I reach help, with php html and mysql I'm confortable but I seem not to get along with javascript and ajax.

I'm trying to make this work since last week...

Once more thanks for all the help,
Miguel

Comment: Please improve your question's title so it's more descriptive.

Comment: About the title,... If I could specify more I would not be asking for help the second time. Can you help? Thanks, Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Well JavaScript is case sensitive so `.onClick` does not mean the same thing as `.onclick`. Change the event to be all lowercase. Bonus points if you use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: *And* `attachEvent` for older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code this way:

```
document.getElementById('ajaxButton').onclick = function () { makeRequest('phpcode.php');}
```

And makeRequest becomes :

```
 function makeRequest(theUrl)
    {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
```

And please replace the :

```
<button id='ajaxButton' method 'GET'>Select</button>
```

by:

```
<input type="button" id="ajaxButton">Select</input>
```

I hope it helps.